# Laravel Eloquent, filtering from pivot table column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I need to filter the active clients from a route using Eloquent.

I'm working with a third party database that I can't modify. In my project I have two models: **Cliente(client)** and **Ruta(route)**, which have a many to many relationship, so I added the belongsToMany relationship in my models.

The only column I'm interested from the pivot table is called DESACTIV, which tells me if a Client is deactivated for a Route.

Ruta model:

```
class Ruta extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'truta';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CODIRUTA';

    public function clientes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class, 'tcpcarut', 'CODIRUTA', 'CODICLIE')->withPivot('DESACTIV');
    }
}
```

Cliente model:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'tcpca';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CODICLIE';

    public function rutas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ruta::class, 'tcpcarut', 'CODICLIE', 'CODIRUTA')->withPivot('DESACTIV');
    }
}
```

What I need is to get the active (or non deactivated) Clients given a specific Route.

I have done it on my controller like this:

```
$miRuta = Ruta::where('CODIRUTA','=',$ruta)->first();
$clientes = array();
foreach ($miRuta->clientes as $cliente){
    if ($cliente->DESACTIV == 0){
        array_push($clientes, $cliente->NOMBCLIE);
        echo end($clientes)."<br/>";
    }
}
```

And it works fine, but I don't think it's elegant. I know this can be archieved through Eloquent, I'm just to noob at it and don't know how to do it.

1. Maybe I could add the filter on the **clientes** method on my **Ruta** model, so it would return only the active Clients.
2. Or maybe It could be best to add a method on the **Cliente** model, like **isDeactivated**

I know it sounds like I know what I'm talking about but I need someone to hold my hand on this, I'm just too noob with Eloquent :/. Examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `wherePivot` method to constrain a relationship based on values in the pivot table.  You just need to add the following to your `Ruta` model

```
public function desactivClientes() {
    return $this->clientes()->wherePivot('DESACTIV', 0);
}
```

And then you just have to modify the rest of your code a bit to use the constrained relationship.  I'm also adding a null check because if this function does return null, which can happen if your table doesn't have a record where `CODIRUTA` matches whatever is in `$ruta`, then it will likely throw a fatal error trying to call a method on a non-object.

```
$miRuta = Ruta::where('CODIRUTA','=',$ruta)->first();
$clientes = array();
if ($miRuta !== null) {
    $clientes = $miRuta->desactivClientes()->pluck('NOMBCLIE');
}
```

Comment: I've never even heard of wherePivot, that's what happens when you start a project without taking the time to know what you're working with. As you saw I implemented the quickest solution to my knowledge so I could just keep moving forward with the project. Thanks, my code is much cleaner this way :D.